# Miglayout, baseline and JTextAreas

Tags: java, swing, miglayout

I am using MigLayout (and I really like it). But I have a problem with Labels in front of a JTextArea.
I have read about the "baseline" keyword. But that does not work in combination with "grow".

Here is an example that shows the problem. 
I expected the label to be aligned at the top (at the same location as the first line of the JTextArea).

Any ideas?

```
public class MigRunner {
  public static void main( String[] args ) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        new MigRunner().run();
      }
    } );
  }

  @UiThread
  private void run() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
    contentPane.setLayout( new MigLayout("wrap 2, fill, debug", "[][grow]", "[grow]") );

    {
      JLabel name = new JLabel( "Description" );
      contentPane.add( name, "baseline" );
      JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
      JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( textArea );

      contentPane.add( scrollPane, "grow, baseline" );
      name.setLabelFor( textArea );
    }

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE );
    frame.setSize( 400, 300 );
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
    frame.setVisible( true );
  }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at [Mig Layout White Paper](http://www.migcalendar.com/miglayout/whitepaper.html) to read more about layout and alignment

Comment: Well, I have read the White Paper. But obviously I could not find the solution there... So any hints are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need the align contraint:

```
JLabel name = new JLabel("Description");
contentPane.add(name, "aligny top");
```

I didn't saw the 3 pixel gap between the baselines of the texts until Jeremias' comment. Well I don't have a nice solution for this, but here is an additional idea to Jeremias "gaptop 3" solution:

```
JTextArea name = new JTextArea("Description");
name.setEditable(false);
contentPane.add(new JScrollPane(name), "aligny top");
```

Comment: Well. Of course I could align the label to the top. But I want it to be aligned at the baseline of the text area.

Comment: Do you want the label at the top or at the baseline? I'm not sure if I understand you correctly. Maybe you could provide a sketch of what you need.

Comment: I'm pretty sure he means alignment of the baselines of the label and the first line of the text area, because that's also what I'm looking for. I ended up using "aligny top, gaptop 3". An ugly work-around and it may not look the same on every operating system but it's good enough until I have time to dive into the MigLayout source code. "aligny top" alone is definitely not the solution.